# How to get value from <bean:write"

Tags: string

```
 <logic:equal name="exField" property="fieldId" value="2131">
 <tr valign="top">
 <td>
 <span class="contenttext"> <b>Account number: </b>             
 <bean:write name="exField" property="value"/>
```

I want to store the value from the above to a string. I used the below code,but getting errors

```
 <%  
    String str = eftDataField.getvalue();
    out.println(str);  
 %>
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Please read this article and try to improve your question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

u can use :

```
<bean:define id="variable" name="exField" property="value"/>

<%  
String str = variable;
out.println(str);  
%>
```